# Python List in List Operation

Tags: python, list, arraylist

My variable and input list is;

```
 nWords = len(embeding_2)
 sequenceLength = 12
 embeding_2 = ['GSSSSSSSSSSS', 'AGGGGGSSSSSS']
```

I created this from this python code;

```
X = []
for i in range(0, nWords-sequenceLength):
    for c in range(1, sequenceLength):
        X.append(embeding_2[i][:c])
```

My sequence length is 12. And i want to that X list in list for each 12 element like this;

```
X = [['G',
 'GS',
 'GSS',
 'GSSS',
 'GSSSS',
 'GSSSSS',
 'GSSSSSS',
 'GSSSSSSS',
 'GSSSSSSSS',
 'GSSSSSSSSS',
 'GSSSSSSSSSS',
 'GSSSSSSSSSSS']
 'A',
 'AG',
 'AGG',
 'AGGG',
 'AGGGG',
 'AGGGGG',
 'AGGGGGS',
 'AGGGGGSS',
 'AGGGGGSSS',
 'AGGGGGSSSS',
 'AGGGGGSSSSS',
 'AGGGGGSSSSSS']]
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out.

```
embeding_2 = ['GSSSSSSSSSSS', 'AGGGGGSSSSSS']
res = []

for i in embeding_2:
    res.append( [i[:j+1] for j in range(len(i))] )
print(res)
```